# ffmpeg_kit_flutter使用時に、H264などのライセンス料が発生しますか？

Tags: ffmpeg, ライセンス

ffmpeg_kit_flutterを使って有料の動画編集ソフトを販売した場合、H264やその他のコーデックのライセンス料が私に発生しますか？

Answer (score 5):

https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter

上記の最後の7.Patensにwikiにある[Patents](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/Patents)をみろとありますので、特許の話はそちらを見てください。なお、弁護士などの法律の専門家では無いため、上記ドキュメントに書かれている内容について法的にどのように解釈すべきかはわかりません。ご自分で判断の上、弁護士に相談する等の対応を行ってください。

なお、[法的にどうなのかという質問はオフトピックとみなされるという意見もあります](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2726/%e6%b3%95%e5%be%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%a4%e3%81%84%e3%81%a6%e3%81%ae%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%82%92%e3%81%a9%e3%81%86%e6%89%b1%e3%81%86%e3%81%8b)ので、スタック・オーバーフローでは法的に保証された回答を得られるのは難しいです。

Comment: お返事ありがとうごいます。難しそうですね。